# What to do when upgrading a custom Plugin from SonarQube 4.5.4 to 5.1.2 concerning BatchExtension/Maven classpath

Tags: sonarqube

We have a custom Java Rules Plugin (Java Plugin Version 3.2) that works well with SonarQube 4.5.4. I just upgraded our Test-Sonarqube machine to 5.1.2 and tested the plugin with it:
* compiled with api 4.5.4 it does not find any issues anymore
* compiled with api 5.1 it works, but the special Maven Classloader we use does not work anymore. The classloader is a BatchExtension that should get a org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject through PicoContainer. This does not seem to work anymore. How should we change it to still get the Maven classpath for classloading?

Answer (score 0):

We are progressively dropping the dependency between SQ and Maven. It was an historical feature that leads to several issues. If you need a tied integration with Maven, then just write a Maven plugin. This Maven plugin will do its job and store results in a file. Then write a SQ Plugin that will read content of this file.

See for example the Clirr integration. The Maven Clirr Plugin generates a report in target/ folder. And the recent versions of SQ Clirr plugin are only able to parse this file. This allows a clean separation of concern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What we do in this plugin is to use some rules that do their work based on the class hierarchy, e.g. some rules check whether a class is "isAssignableFrom" and then do some more checks. We don't want to put these dynamic dependencies into the plugin because they already exist in the maven classpath. Therefore we used this special classloader. Is there any other way to do this? Sonar-Findbugs also needs the class hierarchy if I'm not mistaken, how do they do it?